# Mechanics - Rotational Inertia

Tags: computational-physics, software

I am facing a problem solving a mechanical system which is shown in the scheme below.

[image: system]

We assume that coupling of the two shafts is done with a clutch

Equations:

$$J1*\frac{d\omega1}{dt} + Td(\omega12) + Ts(\phi12) = T_1$$
$$ J2*\frac{d\omega2}{dt} - Td(\omega12) - Ts(\phi12) = T_2$$
    where $$w1 = \frac{d\phi_1}{dt}$$ 
        $$w2 = \frac {d\phi_2}{dt} $$
        $$\phi12 = \phi1 - \phi2$$
        $$\omega12 = \omega_1 - \omega2$$
        $$T_d(\omega12) = c12 * \omega12$$
        $$T_s(\phi12) = k_s * \phi12$$
    $c_12$ and $k_s$ are some coefficients,
So the equations have the form of:
$$\frac{d\phi12}{dt} = \omega_12$$
$$\frac{d\omega12}{dt} = \frac{T_1}{J_1} - \frac{T_2}{J_2} - \frac{T_d(\omega12)}{Jeq} - \frac{T_s(phi12)}{Jeq}$$
    and also i have the dependencies:

$$ccr = 2*Jeq*\omega_n$$
$$\omega_n = \sqrt{\frac {k_s}{Jeq}}$$
    $$Jeq = \frac{J1*J2}{J1+J2}$$

My task is to plot how nonlinear clutch affects the rotational inertia.

Given :

$$T_1(t) = T_0*1(t), T_0 = 1, T_2(t) = 0,$$
$$J_1 = J_2 = 5, c12 = 0, \omega_n = 100$$
$$T_s(\phi12) = k_1*\phi12 + k_2*(\phi12)^3$$
$$ k20 = 10e14, k2 = [10^-6 ... 10^4]$$

I need to plot the $$ \frac{Tsmax}{T_0} = f(log(\frac {k2}{k20}))$$;
So far my progress is:

[image: matlab_plot_1]

But i dont think that the system actually behaves that way. I mean, i expected a lilte more stable curve without such a chaotic behaviour.
Whatsmore i tried to solve it in simscape but got really confused.
Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I was hoping any physicist would look at it and state his opinion. I'll give it a try in cs as well. Thanks for the directions.

Comment: What was your question exactly? Do you just want to know if you're code is correctly plotting the quantity you are trying to plot? Conceptual questions are really a much better fit for this site, debugging someone's code is unlikely to be useful to future users and is also not on topic here. If you are asking **why** the system behaves that way, that is much more on topic here.

Comment: Also, could you please spend some time [converting your equations to proper formulas](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and give a clearer description of the problem, especially definitions for the variables used. Plot axes labels would also be helpful.

Comment: @DougLipinski thanks for the mathematical syntax. the text is way more readable. My question is whether such a mechanical system can behave that way, according to newtonian mechanics of course. The axes are according to my plot so on x we have the $log(\frac{k2}{k20}) $and y translates to $\frac{Tsmax}{Ts}$

Comment: Yes, that's more readable, but you still haven't defined your variables. What physical quantities are k2 and k20? What is Ts and Tsmax? Torques? $\omega$ is angular rotation rate? etc...

Comment: k2 and k20 are some sort of coefficients taking part in scaling the quantities in Ts function. T referes to torques, $\omega$ to angular frequency, J refers to inertia, $\phi$ is angle.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar results using the values you gave.  When $\phi\ll1$, the $\phi^3$ term may be negligible, depending on the value of $k_2$.  With $\phi>1$, the $\phi^3$ term would become significant and probably is the reason we got the results that you show in your graph.

I suspect that $\phi>1$ could not happen in a real system, because the material would rupture first.  I don't remember my failure theories well enough to be too specific, but I would choose a shaft diameter that prevents failure due to maximum shear stress, and due to fatigue.  Based on my experience with steel shafting for ship propulsion, $\phi_{max}$ should be on the order of one milliradian or less. In my experience, the shafting was designed so that the alternating component of torque was no more than 4% of the average torque, to prevent fatigue failures.  Of course, your system could be much different than what I'm thinking of.

By the way, it would be easier to answer your question if we knew more about the actual system, the value of $k_1$ and the units for your values.  Which component has the nonlinear behavior?

Comment: The system i'm currently working on, is mostly experimental. I have no clue whether such a system could be realized in physical world, but according to what u 've just said its rather impossible. I don't really know the value of k1 but I suppose i have somehow compute it using the quantities given. To make matters worse, i chose it arbitrarily as 1. Nonlinear behavior refers to the clutch which couples the two shafts.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden  In the past I have obtained stiffness data on clutches and shaft couplings from the manufacturer product catalogs, available online.  I don't recall seeing any nonlinear stiffness data, probably because the angular deflection was supposed to be small (less than a milliradian).  Sometimes the stiffness data is given as a function of shaft speed.  I recommend you let the manufacturer data be your guide as to whether you need to model the clutch stiffness as a linear or nonlinear element.